# Passing python script's argument into its function as argument

Tags: python, function, arguments

I am trying to write a python script which needs to take input arguments, to be used inside the script when calling a function.

Following is working inside python shell:

```
>>> result = client.call('SoftLayer_Hardware', 'getAllObjects', filter={'id': {'operation': '1442567'}}, limit=300, mask='mask[id, hostname, accountId, primaryIpAddress, softwareComponents[passwords], upstreamHardware[id, hostname], uplinkNetworkComponents[id, name, port, uplink[uplinkComponent[id, hardwareId, name, port]]]]')
>>>
```

This way is also working properly:

```
>>> var_f = {'id': {'operation': '1442567'}}
>>> var_m = "mask[id, hostname, domain, accountId, datacenter, networkVlans, networkManagementIpAddress, primaryBackendIpAddress, primaryIpAddress, softwareComponents[modifyDate, passwords[username, password], softwareLicense[softwareDescriptionId, softwareDescription[longDescription]]], uplinkNetworkComponents[id, name, port, primaryIpAddress, networkVlanId, macAddress, speed, status, uplink[id, uplinkComponent[id, hardwareId, name, port, duplexModeId, maxSpeed, speed, status, networkPortChannelId, networkVlanId]]], upstreamHardware[id, hostname]]"
>>> result = client.call('SoftLayer_Hardware', 'getAllObjects', filter=var_f, limit=300, mask=var_m)
>>>
```

However when I write similar code in script file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import softlayer_api_common as ims
client = ims.connect_to_api(neteng_user=True)

filterinput = sys.argv[1]
maskinput = sys.argv[2]

print 'First argument'
print filterinput
print 'Second argument'
print maskinput

result = client.call('SoftLayer_Hardware', 'getAllObjects', filter=filterinput, limit=300, mask=maskinput)

sys.exit()
```

Then calling it with two argument as follows, it is failing:

```
$ ./imsquery "{'id': {'operation': '1442567'}}" "mask[id, hostname, domain, accountId, datacenter, networkVlans, networkManagementIpAddress, primaryBackendIpAddress, primaryIpAddress, softwareComponents[modifyDate, passwords[username, password], softwareLicense[softwareDescriptionId, softwareDescription[longDescription]]], uplinkNetworkComponents[id, name, port, primaryIpAddress, networkVlanId, macAddress, speed, status, uplink[id, uplinkComponent[id, hardwareId, name, port, duplexModeId, maxSpeed, speed, status, networkPortChannelId, networkVlanId]]], upstreamHardware[id, hostname]]"
First argument
{'id': {'operation': '1442567'}}
Second argument
mask[id, hostname, domain, accountId, datacenter, networkVlans, networkManagementIpAddress, primaryBackendIpAddress, primaryIpAddress, softwareComponents[modifyDate, passwords[username, password], softwareLicense[softwareDescriptionId, softwareDescription[longDescription]]], uplinkNetworkComponents[id, name, port, primaryIpAddress, networkVlanId, macAddress, speed, status, uplink[id, uplinkComponent[id, hardwareId, name, port, duplexModeId, maxSpeed, speed, status, networkPortChannelId, networkVlanId]]], upstreamHardware[id, hostname]]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./imsquery", line 15, in <module>
    result = client.call('SoftLayer_Hardware', 'getAllObjects', filter=filterinput, limit=300, mask=maskinput)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 265, in call
    return self.transport(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/transports.py", line 247, in __call__
    raise exceptions.TransportError(ex.response.status_code, str(ex))
SoftLayer.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(500): 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: https://internal.applb.dal01.softlayer.local/v3/internal/xmlrpc/SoftLayer_Hardware
$
```

Looks the script's input arguments are being taken into the variables, however having problem with using those variable's contents when calling the function, not working with this syntax. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fails because of argument `filterinput`. It is expected to be `dict` type as input to internal function. But being passing from command line it doesn't convert  to `dict` automatically. Here, try to print your `filterinput` type:

**Print Output:**

```sh
...
First argument
{'id': {'operation': '1442567'}}
<class 'str'>
Second argument
...
```

You have to convert it from `str` to `dict` manually using `json.loads()`, for example

**Code:**

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import json
import softlayer_api_common as ims
client = ims.connect_to_api(neteng_user=True)

filterinput = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
maskinput = sys.argv[2]
...
```

**BUT:** Don't forget use json standard for your argument, so instead of `"{'id': {'operation': '1442567'}}"` you should pass `'{"id": {"operation": 1442567}}'`:

```sh
$ ./imsquery '{"id": {"operation": 1442567}}' "mask[id, hostname, domain, accountId, datacenter, networkVlans, networkManagementIpAddress, primaryBackendIpAddress, primaryIpAddress, softwareComponents[modifyDate, passwords[username, password], softwareLicense[softwareDescriptionId, softwareDescription[longDescription]]], uplinkNetworkComponents[id, name, port, primaryIpAddress, networkVlanId, macAddress, speed, status, uplink[id, uplinkComponent[id, hardwareId, name, port, duplexModeId, maxSpeed, speed, status, networkPortChannelId, networkVlanId]]], upstreamHardware[id, hostname]]"
```

**Print Output:**

```sh
First argument
{'id': {'operation': 1442567}}
<class 'dict'>
Second argument
...
```

Comment: It worked straight away after changing filterinput type to dict and correcting the json format as you recommended. Thanks a lot @trsvchn

Comment: I'm glad to hear that!)

Comment: btw, it is recommended to use `argparse` when you have such complex argument inputs